# Wordpress : add permlinks to entire div

Tags: wordpress, loops, post, permalinks

[image]

Hello, professional coders.
Sorry for my poor English, and I know nothing about code.

I want to add permlink to each post item from blog-layout.php file.
It is related to category page.

I found post loop in there, and want to know how to add permalink.

reference site : http://blog.lgchem.com/category/company-story/

Since I am not a developer, step-by-step instructions would truly be appreciated.

```
// Start the main loop
while ( have_posts() ): the_post();
    // Set the time stamps for timeline month/year check
    $alignment_class = '';
    if( $blog_layout == 'timeline' ) {
        $post_timestamp = get_the_time( 'U' );
        $post_month = date( 'n', $post_timestamp );
        $post_year = get_the_date( 'o' );
        $current_date = get_the_date( 'o-n' );

        // Set the correct column class for every post
        if( $post_count % 2 ) {
            $alignment_class = 'fusion-left-column';
        } else {
            $alignment_class = 'fusion-right-column';
        }

        // Set the timeline month label
        if ( $prev_post_month != $post_month ||
             $prev_post_year != $post_year
        ) {

            if( $post_count > 1 ) {
                echo '</div>';
            }
            echo sprintf( '<h3 class="fusion-timeline-date">%s</h3>', get_the_date( Avada()->settings->get( 'timeline_date_format' ) ) );
            echo '<div class="fusion-collapse-month">';
        }
    }

    // Set the has-post-thumbnail if a video is used. This is needed if no featured image is present.
    $thumb_class = '';
    if ( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'pyre_video', true ) ) {
        $thumb_class = ' has-post-thumbnail';
    }

    $post_classes = sprintf( '%s %s %s post fusion-clearfix', $post_class, $alignment_class, $thumb_class );
    ob_start();
    post_class( $post_classes );
    $post_classes = ob_get_clean();
```

// post item

```
    echo sprintf( '<div id="post-%s" %s>', get_the_ID(), $post_classes);
        // Add an additional wrapper for grid layout border
        if ( $blog_layout == 'grid' ) {
            echo '<div class="fusion-post-wrapper">';
        }

            // Get featured images for all but large-alternate layout
            if ( Avada()->settings->get( 'featured_images' ) &&
                 $blog_layout == 'large-alternate'
            ) {
                get_template_part( 'new-slideshow' );
            }

            // Get the post date and format box for alternate layouts
            if ( $blog_layout == 'large-alternate' ||
                 $blog_layout == 'medium-alternate'
            ) {
                echo '<div class="fusion-date-and-formats">';

                    /**
                     * avada_blog_post_date_adn_format hook
                     *
                     * @hooked avada_render_blog_post_date - 10 (outputs the HTML for the date box)
                     * @hooked avada_render_blog_post_format - 15 (outputs the HTML for the post format box)
                     */
                    do_action( 'avada_blog_post_date_and_format' );

                echo '</div>';
            }

            // Get featured images for all but large-alternate layout
            if ( Avada()->settings->get( 'featured_images' ) &&
                 $blog_layout != 'large-alternate'
            ) {
                get_template_part( 'new-slideshow' );
            }

            // post-content-wrapper only needed for grid and timeline
            if ( $blog_layout == 'grid' ||
                 $blog_layout == 'timeline'
            ) {
                echo '<div class="fusion-post-content-wrapper">';
            }

                // Add the circles for timeline layout
                if ( $blog_layout == 'timeline' ) {
                    echo '<div class="fusion-timeline-circle"></div>';
                    echo '<div class="fusion-timeline-arrow"></div>';
                }

                echo '<div class="fusion-post-content">';

                    // Render the post title
                    echo avada_render_post_title( get_the_ID() );

                    // Render post meta for grid and timeline layouts
                    if ( $blog_layout == 'grid' ||
                         $blog_layout == 'timeline'
                    ) {
                        echo avada_render_post_metadata( 'grid_timeline' );

                        if ( ( Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta' ) && ( ! Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_author' ) || ! Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_date' ) || ! Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_cats' ) || ! Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_tags' ) || ! Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_comments' ) || ! Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_read' ) ) ) &&
                             Avada()->settings->get( 'excerpt_length_blog' ) > 0
                        ) {
                            echo '<div class="fusion-content-sep"></div>';
                        }
                    // Render post meta for alternate layouts
                    } elseif( $blog_layout == 'large-alternate' ||
                              $blog_layout == 'medium-alternate'
                    ) {
                        echo avada_render_post_metadata( 'alternate' );
                    }

                    echo '<div class="fusion-post-content-container">';

                        /**
                         * avada_blog_post_content hook
                         *
                         * @hooked avada_render_blog_post_content - 10 (outputs the post content wrapped with a container)
                         */
                        do_action( 'avada_blog_post_content' );
                        do_action( 'avada_blog_post_date_and_format' );

                    echo '</div>';


                echo '</div>'; // end post-content

                if( $blog_layout == 'medium' ||
                    $blog_layout == 'medium-alternate'
                ) {
                    echo '<div class="fusion-clearfix"></div>';
                }

                // Render post meta data according to layout
                if ( ( Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta' ) && ( ! Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_author' ) || ! Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_date' ) || ! Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_cats' ) || ! Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_tags' ) || ! Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_comments' ) || ! Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_read' ) ) ) ) {
                    echo '<div class="fusion-meta-info">';
                        if ( $blog_layout == 'grid' ||
                             $blog_layout == 'timeline'
                        ) {
                            // Render read more for grid/timeline layouts
                            echo '<div class="fusion-alignleft">';
                                if ( ! Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_read' ) ) {
                                    $link_target = '';
                                    if( fusion_get_page_option( 'link_icon_target', get_the_ID() ) == 'yes' ||
                                        fusion_get_page_option( 'post_links_target', get_the_ID() ) == 'yes' ) {
                                        $link_target = ' target="_blank"';
                                    }
                                    echo sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="fusion-read-more"%s>%s</a>', get_permalink(), $link_target, apply_filters( 'avada_blog_read_more_link', __( 'Read More', 'Avada' ) ) );
                                }
                            echo '</div>';

                            // Render comments for grid/timeline layouts
                            echo '<div class="fusion-alignright">';
                                if ( ! Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_comments' ) ) {
                                    if( ! post_password_required( get_the_ID() ) ) {
                                        comments_popup_link('<i class="fusion-icon-bubbles"></i>&nbsp;' . __( '0', 'Avada' ), '<i class="fusion-icon-bubbles"></i>&nbsp;' . __( '1', 'Avada' ), '<i class="fusion-icon-bubbles"></i>&nbsp;' . '%' );
                                    } else {
                                        echo sprintf( '<i class="fusion-icon-bubbles"></i>&nbsp;%s', __( 'Protected', 'Avada' ) );
                                    }
                                }
                            echo '</div>';
                        } else {
                            // Render all meta data for medium and large layouts
                            if ( $blog_layout == 'large' || $blog_layout == 'medium' ) {
                                echo avada_render_post_metadata( 'standard' );
                            }

                            // Render read more for medium/large and medium/large alternate layouts
                            echo '<div class="fusion-alignright">';
                                if ( ! Avada()->settings->get( 'post_meta_read' ) ) {
                                    $link_target = '';
                                    if( fusion_get_page_option( 'link_icon_target', get_the_ID() ) == 'yes' ||
                                        fusion_get_page_option( 'post_links_target', get_the_ID() ) == 'yes' ) {
                                        $link_target = ' target="_blank"';
                                    }
                                    echo sprintf( '<a href="%s" class="fusion-read-more"%s>%s</a>', get_permalink(), $link_target, __( 'Read More', 'Avada' ) );
                                }
                            echo '</div>';
                        }
                    echo '</div>'; // end meta-info
                }
            if ( $blog_layout == 'grid' ||
                 $blog_layout == 'timeline'
            ) {
                echo '</div>' ;

                // end post-content-wrapper
            }
        if ( $blog_layout == 'grid' ) {
            echo '</div>'; // end post-wrapper
        }
    echo '</div>'; // end post
    // post item


    // Adjust the timestamp settings for next loop
    if ( $blog_layout == 'timeline' ) {
        $prev_post_timestamp = $post_timestamp;
        $prev_post_month = $post_month;
        $prev_post_year = $post_year;
        $post_count++;
    }
endwhile; // end have_posts()

if ( $blog_layout == 'timeline' &&
     $post_count > 1
) {
    echo '</div>';
}

echo '</div>'; // end posts-container
```

Comment: Hire a developer? We also need money to buy our food ;) but, did you check codex if wordpress? Search for: `get_permalink();` function

Answer (score 0):

There's several approaches you could do.

You could either link it to whatever you like in Wordpress CMS backend.

If you want to modify the source code for all the items, you could wrap your div in something like this:

```
 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
```

I would recommend that you have a child theme if you're going to change the source, in that case when your theme (Avada) gets updated, your changes wont disappear.

Read more on permalinks on Wordpress docs: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink
https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks